# Is there any good node modules to connect google shortener API to shorten a long URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-url-shortener

I am working with Node.js , and trying to shorten a long URL , i am trying to connect to google shortener API ,  if found in the API documentation for Node.js

[google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client)

but it only has codes for convert the short URL to a long URL ,

And i found [node-google-url-shorter](https://github.com/IskenHuang/node-google-url-shorter)

this doesn't use an API key , since i may send over 10,000 request per day this is not good and it is not a maintaining repo i think .

and this one [google-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-url) , seems this one is depicted as well .

So is there any other good node modules .

I want to shorten a long URL .

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I wouldn't expect a "recommend a library" question from someone with that much rep points... you should know better

Comment: I have done a lot of research before posting the question , i need a node module to do my task , @ giorgio so what should be my question ? so if you were me how do you ask this question , sorry my english is not good because i am not a native english speaker

Comment: I wouldn't ;) As we have all agreed questions like this `"tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"`. [Read more about it on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question). But as you actually already _have found_ some modules, you could easily convert this into a question like: `I currently use module x and y, but it doesn't do this or that. How can I achieve it?`. And don't forget to show us what you've tried already to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question since there are no answers , i found a node module .

[googleapis-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis-plus)

to get a shorter URL you have to call

```
client.urlshortener.url.insert
```

Here is an example

```
  function get_shorter_url(config,long_url,callback) {

    var googleapis  = require('googleapis-plus');

    var api_key = "your api key";
    var long_url = "your long url";

        try {

                googleapis
                    .discover('urlshortener', 'v1')
                    .execute(function(err, client) {

                        if( err) { // handle discovery errors

                            callback(err);
                        } else {

                            var getShortUrl = client.urlshortener.url.insert({ longUrl: long_url })
                                .withApiKey(api_key);

                            getShortUrl.execute(function(err, shortUrlDetails) {

                                if(err) {

                                    callback(err);
                                } else {

                                    callback(null,shortUrlDetails.id);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

            } catch ( err ) {

                console.log("there was an exception "+err);
                callback(err, null);
            }
    }
```